# Sommerfeld Integral Evaluation - Hankel Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

I was studying theory of electromagnetic from the book Time-harmonic Electromagnetic Fields by Roger Harrington and what caught up my attention was following identity:
 $$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}k_{0}r}}{r} =
\frac{1}{2\mathrm{i}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{H}_{0}^{\left(2\right)} \left(\rho\,\sqrt{\,k_{0}^{2} - k_{z}^{2}\,}\,\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k_{z}z}\,\mathrm{d}k_{z}
$$
where $k_{0}$ is wave number in vacuum, $\mathrm{H}_{0}^{\left(2\right)}\left(x\right)$ is Hankel function of second kind and
$$
r^{2} = \rho^{2} +z^{2}
$$
Proving mentioned identity is quite trivial given the fact that we can calculate electromagnetic fields of a point source using other methods. However in order to solve other problems I found myself in need to know following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{H}_{n}^{\left(2\right)} \left(\rho\,\sqrt{\,k_{0}^{2} - k_{z}^{2}\,}\,\right)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k_{z}z}\,\mathrm{d}k_{z}
$$
Evaluating this integral maybe possible in a similar fashion but I was unable to reach it.

So I would be more than grateful if anyone could help.

Regards.

Comment: Perhaps you could outline for us what makes the latter integral so challenging with respect to the former one.